# Force subclass to implement abstract override method

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I have an abstract class with some abstract methods that subclasses need to implement.

```dart
abstract class BlockData {
  Widget build();

  BlockData get value;
}

class NumberData extends BlockData {

  NumberData(Function updateCallback) : super(updateCallback);

  // trying to remove either of the below methods throws a compiler error as expected
  @override
  BlockWidget build() {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  BlockData get value => this;
}
```

As expected, my subclass is forced to implement them. However, I also want to force my class to implement a custom `==` and `hashcode` method. When I override these methods in my abstract class with an abstract implementation, they are completely ignored and the subclass is allowed to not implement them.

```dart
abstract class BlockData {
  Widget build();

  BlockData get value;

  @override
  bool operator ==(other);

  @override
  int get hashCode;
}

// this should throw an error since it doesn't implement == or hashcode, but it doesn't
class NumberData extends BlockData {

  NumberData(Function updateCallback) : super(updateCallback);

  @override
  BlockWidget build() {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  BlockData get value => this;
}
```

This is different from the behavior in Java, where you can make an abstract method that overrides a superclass and force a subclass to have a custom implementation. Is there any way to force this in Dart, and for that matter, is this expected behavior?

Comment: It is expected. `==` and `hashCode` are implemented in the `Object` class so there is no requirement for `NumberData` to explicitly override them.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore while that's true, in other languages the abstract method declaration shadows the implementation in Object. While I know that it's not strictly necessary for the subclass to override equals/hashcode to work, in applications where you're expecting a proper == implementation it can help prevent bugs to enforce a custom implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. Dart is its own language. This is expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

you can just do like

```dart
FutureOr<void> myFunction();
```

and it will force any inheritor to override it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  [There is a request for a `@mustOverride` annotation in `package:meta`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30175) (and also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28250).

It's also expected that [the empty method declaration in the abstract class does not hide the default implementation from its base class](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34427).